# charset in windows server 2016 not displaying french char

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, encoding

I have developed a java web application that runs under tomcat.
on my development server (windows 10) my browser is accepting french characters.

However on the production server (windows server 2016) the browsers are replacing the french characters with `?`. Even while accessing the production webapp from my development server, there is still an issue with the encoding.

Would you advise what might be the problem?

Comment: Use [UTF-8 everywhere](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q8).

Answer (score 0):

Background: For French suffices Windows-1252, MS Latin-1. There is ISO-8859-1, official Latin-1, which does not have **œ** (oe) - though it has **æ** (ae). There is the added complication that browsers will interprete ISO-8859-1 as Windows-1252, since HTML5 offically. But a java server would still need to use Windows-1252 for its Writers. And mind, that the flawed ISO-8859-1 is the default encoding of HTTP. However as most French characters are available in ISO-8859-1, that should not be the error.

As java uses internally in String Unicode, switching to UTF-8 would seem best, allowing many special symbols, and foreign scripts.

The error must somehow come from the default encoding, which on a French Windows will be Windows-1252 and on a server might be anything. Either file system or database, or even for hard-coded strings, say in JSPs the (jsp) compiler encoding.
Where the text originates for a file, ensure that the encoding of the file is specified by the Reader. As you have found out, default encodings are for not portable files.
Do not use FileReader/FileWriter, old utility classes where one cannot specify the encoding.